# New Thermostat Won't Engage Plinth Heating in Kitchen Island

Tags: hvac, thermostat, hydronic, hydro-air

I have two plinth heaters on either side of my kitchen island. Since the rest of the house is hydronic, I presume that these are hydronic (there is a zone valve at the boiler) with electric fans because they have fan speed switches and not much heat comes out unless these are on.

I have just tried to replace the existing thermostat with a Honeywell RTH2300. I barely use this zone so I went with something easy. However even though the wires are hooked up the same way (G Y W Rh Rc) and set the temp to engage, nothing happens. The fans don't even turn on. The thermostat looks like it is engaged but the fans don't come on. One unique thing I have never seen before is that this thermostat has a switch that says gas/oil and electric. My system fits both descriptions (ie I have a gas run boiler but I have a G wire to allow the thermostat to call the fans when it calls for heat).

I have tried both switch settings with no results. Could this thermostat not be compatible with this heat zone?

Comment: Can you trace the wires that control the zone valve on that heat zone?

Answer (score 1):

Stupid me. The fan has a delay of a few minutes after the thermostat calls for heat. I set it to gas and called for heat and waited 10 or so minutes and the fan came on.